# In Jenkins How can i use FxCop Runner Plugin with Reference .dlls that additionally to the .dll to be analyse?

Tags: jenkins, reference, fxcop

In Jenkins How can i use FxCop Runner Plugin with Reference .dlls that additionally to the .dll to be analyse? I'm using FxCop Runner Plugin for jenkins in order to Analyse the builds. But i got following error
One or more referenced assemblies could not be found. Use the '/directory' or '/reference' switch to specify additional assembly reference search paths.

How can I add references with the jenkins runner plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of FxCop are you running ?

Two things:

1 Add the /gac flag to FxCop

2 Change the FxCopCmd.exe.config file to AssemblyReferenceResolveMode from StrongName to StrongNameIgnoringVersion

OR (this is NOT what you want, but) create a FxCop Project File and add all the references there; then call it in cmd.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0\FxCopCmd.exe" /project:"C:\Jenkins\jobs\8.5-StaticCodeAnalsis\Project.FxCop" /out:"C:\Jenkins\jobs\8.5-StaticCodeAnalsis\workspace\FxCopReport.xml"
```

[image]